# Low Fee caused Invalid Transaction after a month. Coins still not back in wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

I was moving 1 BTC from an old bitcoin core wallet to a cold storage and put a low fee. Didn't realize how low it was until after the transaction was made. The transaction was pending unconfirmed the past month but just went to invalid.

Loaded up my BTCcore wallet and funds are not back in it. Is there something else I need to do as I would like to send it again but with a higher fee.

Here is my transaction ID if that helps:

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/7adf39c5a048290b0697f847246afed11509db5cac099d3a060bdb3787052936

Any advice would be much appreciated. I did check RBF but sadly don't have any other BTC in the wallet so not sure I can do anything about that.

Thanks for any help

Comment: According to some alternative explorer, the transaction seems valid and queued for confirmation. Congrats! You can use Child-Pays-For-Parent for faster confirmation time.

Comment: Thank you! So would I need to add some BTC to the sending or receiving address? Right now both are empty as I sent the full balance to my Ledger

Comment: One solution would be to import the utxo address' private key to Bitcoin Core, and sending it back to yourself (Child-Pays-For-Parent). Another solution would be to abandon the transaction from Bitcoin Core, and send the txin to yourself with a larger fee (Replace-By-Fee).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction Status: 0 / not confirmed, not in mempool](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/transaction-status-0-not-confirmed-not-in-mempool)

Comment: I will research using that method but if I can just cancel it and resend it with a higher fee that sounds like the best idea. Why hasn't this method been discussed enough in other forums? Is it risky to do so? Seems like the go to is RBF/CPFP but the canceling seems like the better option right?

Comment: Your transaction is now confirmed. Did the funds pop up in your wallet?